# Drawing on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is taking some time before it is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have a *AVCaptureSession* with a *AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*. I'm drawing a layer and adding it to the preview layer in the *captureOutput* method. The problem is that it takes around 160 frames for my drawn layer to be displayed in the preview layer.  How can I get the drawn layer to appear in the preview layer since frame #1?

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection){

    i += 1
    print("\(i)")

    layer.removeFromSuperlayer
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160, height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    previewLayer.layer.addSublayer(layer)

}
```